git clone results in "error: RPC failed; curl transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining"
I'm facing this particular error while attempting to clone a large-sized repo (7 GB) from GitHub:
Cloning into 'fc'
remote: Enumerating objects: 19029, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (19029/19029), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (11551/11551), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
error: 39 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

I have set up a git configuration in order to fix this to no avail. Before doing so, the error was different -
error: rpc failed curl 92 http/2 stream 5 was not closed cleanly: cancel (err 8)

As for why this is happening, it's most likely due to my poor internet connection which cannot be currently fixed. I don't have an antivirus. Modifying --depth does not work either.
Here's the git config itself:
[filter "lfs"]
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
[user]
    name = #
    email = #
[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = "'' "
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = "'' "
    trustExitCode = true
[core]
    compression = 0
[http]
    postBuffer = 52428800
    maxRequestBuffer = 100M
    version = HTTP/1.1
    lowSpeedLimit = 1000
    lowSpeedTime = 300


Even git clone --depth=1 doesn't help?

@phd Probably. Is there a difference between --depth=1 and --depth 1? I'm a little bit new to git. If there's not, then yes, it doesn't help.

Nop, no difference.

@phd Wait, I think I realized what I done wrong. I wrote "git clone  --depth 1" instead of "git clone --depth 1 ". I'm not sure if that'll help, but I'll definitely check it.

Shouldn't be any difference either.

@phd Alright. Let me know if you have some kind of resolve to this.

I've been having the same problem. I set up SSH and was able to clone the repository without issues. The GitHub documentation was easy to follow and it took less than 10 minutes to get it set up.
In my case, the issue wasn't due to network reliability. A colleague on the same network could clone without a problem. I also tried a different network on the same laptop, but got the same issue. Setting the depth to 1 also didn't help me.
Previous to this, I tried changing different Git configuration settings, but it didn't help.
